# Magento 2 sample data installed but not showing

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I have just installed Magento 2. I think I have installed the sample data. I did `php bin/magento sampledata:deploy` , `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` however the sample data isn't showing on my magento site. Why isn't it showing?

Comment: Does it show in the admin section?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: No :( it doesnt show in the admin section!

Comment: Did you 'authenticate ' after running `/bin/magento sampledata:deploy`? Check magento2/app/etc/config.php or run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` is there a `Magento_SampleData` listed?

Comment: You can also use `bin/magento module:status` to list currently installed modules.

Comment: How do you know it imported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue.
thx to @Steve-johnson for pointing me to `bin/magento module:status` where I was not able to see the presence of the Modules '*SampleData'.

I was not able to see sample data after the following command:

`$ ./bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

Since my terminal was small I had to scroll up to read the following error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 88614883 bytes) in Users/.../public_html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 247`

It seemed that the sample data wasn't installed because of lack of memory.

So... I had to increase the memory to be able to install the sample data.

`$ php -dmemory_limit=1024M ./bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

After that and `$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I notice the sample data.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how and where to run these commands

Comment: @SalmanDalalyou can run these commands from command line in the root of your Magento installation.

Comment: Thanks @hans2103 I will check that